# Robot Framework Appium: Implicit wait is ignored

Tags: android, appium, robotframework, wait

I am using Robot Framework-AppiumLibrary to test an Android hybrid mobile app (webview elements) and during implicit wait, the timeout I set is being ignored. For example, I set 5 seconds to wait for a text/element but it extends the time to ~35 seconds waiting time before it fails the test case if element is not found. I need the timeout to be precise on my tests.

Here is an example script:

```
Wait Until Page Contains    Stackoverflow    timeout=5
```

Have tried the following ways:
 1. Set Appium timeout
 2. Set Desired capabilities timeout: newCommandTimeout, autoWebViewTimeout, and any other timeout i can find.
 3. Set Wait Until Page .... keyword timeout=0

How can I make a Appium Library Wait until... keyword follow the implicit wait timeout? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the log, pls?